# simulator is not updating in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, simulator

I'm new to react native and in every tutorial on youTube, they just save their code in the code editor and changes can be done on the simulator as soon they reload the simulator.

but this is not working for me. in my case simulator shows the only splash screen and then app gets closed
if I try to open the app by clicking it, it shows error screen which does not change even if I delete that error line code and run the simulator again through the terminal

below is my code.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'; 
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native'; 
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

    const firebaseConfig = { apiKey: "AIzaSyCoC87qeRN995YBOUrUDAcIVQS4i33FuY4", authDomain: "helloreactapp.firebaseapp.com", databaseURL: "https://helloreactapp.firebaseio.com", projectId: "helloreactapp", storageBucket: "helloreactapp.appspot.com", messagingSenderId: "180878232923" };

   const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); import {Container, Content, Header, Form, Input, Item, Button, Label } from 'native-base';

    export default class App extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){   super(props)   this.state = ({
        email: '',
        password: ''   }) }

    signUpUser = (email,password) => {

      try {

        if(this.state.password.length<6){
          alert("please enter atleast 6 character")
        }

         firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailandPassword(email,password)

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.toString())   } }

      render() {
        return (
                 <Container styles={styles.container}>
                  <Form>
                    <Item floatingLabel>
                        <Label>Email</Label>
                          <Input
                          onChangeText={(email) => this.setState(email)}
                          />
                    </Item>
                    <Item floatingLabel>
                        <Label>Password</Label>
                          <Input
                          secureTextEntry={true}
                          onChangeText={(password) => this.setState(password)}
                          />
                    </Item>
                    <Button style={{marginTop: 10}}
                    full
                    rounded
                    primary
                    onPress = {() => this.signUpUser(this.state.email,this.state.password)}
                    ><Text>Sign Up</Text>
                    </Button>
                  </Form>
                 </Container>
        );   } }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({   container: {
        flex: 1,
         justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
        padding: 18,   },   welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,   },   instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,   }, });
```

here is the simulator screen:[image]

Comment: Error showing in screen is not updating after code change

Answer (score 0):

`Unexpected token, expected "}"` it looks like you forgot a "}" in your `App` file... Error should also be visible in the Metro bundler window...

Comment: i checked it and corrected the code but simulator screen is not updated as per my new code that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

If this happens to you on the iOS simulator and you've already tried reinstalling `watchman` as such `rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/watchman && brew uninstall watchman && brew install watchman` then what worked for me instead was running a different version of the simulator i.e., iPhone XS Max, etc.